# NG5 & RxJS: Make an Http Call on Load and Use the Data Once Available

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I need to make a call in Angular 5 on app load and then use the returned data throughout the app. The goal is to pre-load the data. Later, I need to use the data immediately, or wait for it to load, without duplicating the call.

I believe I have achieved the desired functionality as shown in [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/R8cP7Y3EjKobOnmW1Hh1?p=preview), but I didn't do it correctly at all. I just made the call and subscribed to it right away so the observable is `hot`. So, this is mistake one - not making the observable `hot` correctly.

Here is my code, note the commented parts:

```
  constructor(private http: Http) {
    const testUrl: string = 'http://httpbin.org/delay/3';
    this.vlData = this.http.get(testUrl)
      .map( (res) => res.json() ).publishReplay(1).refCount()
      .catch( (err) => Observable.throw(error.json().error) )
      //.publish();

//this.vlData.connect();

  this.vlData.subscribe(
  (next) => {console.log('INITIAL DATA RETURN: ', next)},
  (err) => {console.log(`ERR: ${err}`)});
```

}

**THE QUESTION:** Is this code "bad"? If so, how do I accomplish the same result using the commented out operators `publish` and `connect`? Do I need to here?

P.S. I have about 15 articles / SO posts on the topic open, none of them seem to help, or I don't get it.

Comment: You never actually call `subscribe` or do anything with the observable returned from the service.

Comment: @Igor (Igoresha) I call subscribe inside the server, as you can see in the code I posted here. I also call additional subscribes from the home component, as you can see in the plunk. I just log the response, that's all I need for the purposes of this question.

Comment: Maybe I am looking at the wrong Plunk then because I do not see it there. I just see this in the 1st method `this.vlDataService.subscribeToVlDataObservable();`

Comment: @Igor Weird, I just double checked the plunk.

Comment: You want to call the server once and share the result with all your subscriptions ?

Comment: @ibenjelloun Yes.

Comment: Never mind, I am looking at the wrong service and component in the plunk...

Comment: @Igor My bad on that, I was re-using an old plunk of mine.

Comment: I read through the other service and your question again. You are making it more complex than it needs to be (*unless I am not understanding the fundamental requirement*). I updated my code below. To recap, just store the returned observable in a private field and return it any time the method is called if it has a value. That is all you need to do. There is no need to `connect` or `publish`.

Comment: @Igor By returned observable value do you mean the observable or the actual returned value. I can't do the latter, because sometimes I need the value before it's done loading. Anyway, I upvoted, ty for the help, don't spend too much time on it.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, I meant the created observable *not* the value it produces.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ensure that the data is cached after the first call then store the observable in a private field and return it after it has a value. The returned value(s) will resolve just the first time and be served up again on subsequent calls.

**services/vl-data.service.ts** *(body code)*

*Note that this code was taken from the plunk link you posted, not the code posted in the question.*

```
private _vlData: Observable<any>;

constructor(private http: Http) {}

getVlData(): Observable<any> {
    if(!this._vlData) {
        const testUrl: string = 'http://httpbin.org/delay/3';
        this._vlData = this.http.get(testUrl)
          .map( (res) => res.json() )
          .catch( (err) => Observable.throw(error.json().error) );
      }
    return this._vlData;
}
```

---

Some side notes:

1. Try not to put any business logic or calls in your constructors, this makes them more difficult to test and ideally you want executions to occur explicitly instead of as a side effect of some other process (*like when your service is created which you*).
2. You should consider using `HttpClient` instead of `Http`, the latter is considered obsolete/deprecated.
3. You should consider using the RxJs pipable operators over the "older" patch operators.